# Cocoa method naming convention

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, naming-conventions

which of the following namings is more 'right'?

```
- (void) forPrimaryKeySetValue:(id)value
```

or

```
- (void) setValueForPrimaryKey:(id)value
```

what it does : its a NSManagedObject category method, which searches the userInfo of the entity for a key primaryKey and if it is pressend, than sets the value of the corresponding(primaryKey) attribute to value

Comment: My first reaction is that the prefix `set` should be reserved for instance variables.

Comment: I think the second would be the preferred one, see also `-[NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey:]`

Answer (score 2):

What does the method do? The second is the default setter name for an ivar called `valueForPrimaryKey`. If all you're doing is setting a primary key, the method should probably be called `setPrimaryKey:` - the valueFor is superfluous.

I don't fully follow your explanation of what the method does, but I guess you're setting it up so that you can call this method on any managed object, and it will set the primary key value if it exists, otherwise it will fail safely? In that case, something like `safeSetPrimaryKey:`? I'm not sure of a convention for this type of method, but you shouldn't stray too far from the standard if it's just a glorified setter, and the value stuff is still confusing.